# Remove stringified list of unicode strings in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a df that looks like this:

```
pd.DataFrame(["[u'one_element']", "[u'two_elememts', u'two_elements']", "[u'three_elements', u'three_elements', u'three_elements']"])

    0
0   [u'one_element']
1   [u'two_elememts', u'two_elements']
2   [u'three_elements', u'three_elements', u'three_elements']
```

Those elements are strings:

```
type(df[0].iloc[2]) == str
```

The end result should look like:

```
    0
0   one_element
1   two_elememts, two_elements
2   three_elements, three_elements, three_elements
```

I tried with:

```
df[column] = df[column].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('[u').rstrip(']').replace("u'","").replace("'",""))
```

But obviously this is slow when you have many rows.

Is there a better way to do it? The df has many columns of different types: strings, integers, floats.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex and strip i.e

```
df[0] = df[0].str.strip("[]").str.replace("u'|'",'')

0                                       one_element
1                        two_elememts, two_elements
2    three_elements, three_elements, three_elements
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need map, you can use the [str](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html) attribute for pandas Series:

```
(df[0].str.lstrip('[u')
           .str.rstrip(']')
           .str.replace("u'","")
           .str.replace("'","")))
```

achieves the same result but does not use map

```
0                                       one_element
1                        two_elememts, two_elements
2    three_elements, three_elements, three_elements
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the **ast module**.

```
import pandas as pd
import ast
df = pd.DataFrame(["[u'one_element']", "[u'two_elememts', u'two_elements']", "[u'three_elements', u'three_elements', u'three_elements']"])
print(df[0].apply(lambda x: ", ".join(ast.literal_eval(x))))
```

**Output:**

```
0                                       one_element
1                        two_elememts, two_elements
2    three_elements, three_elements, three_elements
Name: 0, dtype: object
```